# need information about version in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded a new app into App store(1.3.0), two days later they rejected my app for "***Metadata Rejected***" here they explained in resolution center that "***We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use on an iOS device.***" & "***0.3.0 Before You Submit: Info Needed (iOS)***".I'd made a demo video.

Here my doubt is iTunes asking the information about the 0.2.0. i given 1.3.0 version in iTunes connect because in local i maintaining the versions like 1.0.0,1.0.1,1.0.2,1.2.0,1.2.1 upto 1.3.0 so i entered 1.3.0 version.Is it wrong? 
What information i want to give to iTunes connect?

For New app we must give a version 1.0 Only or we can give like 1.3.0 or 2.1.0  for new app in iTunes Connect.
Help me

Comment: Yes you can give version numbers like 1.3.0 also that is not a problem.

Comment: thanks Yogesh. then why they asking information about 0.2.0. & what i want to explain them

Comment: @TestiOS  If features require an environment that is hard to replicate or require specific hardware, be prepared to provide a demo video or the hardware.

Comment: @TestiOS don't consider `0.3.0` as a version number it is just may be a serial number of the issue. Please check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

As Yogesh said there is no problem with using version numbers like 1.3.0,2.1.0.

And don't consider `0.3.0` as a version number it is just may be a serial number to the issue. For example in the  below image 0.4.0 is not the `Version/Build` number.

[image]

As per `apple technical notes` please check the following checklist regarding the `Version/Build` Number

- For each new version of your App, you need to invent a new Version
  Number. This number should be a greater value than the last Version
  number that you used. Though you may provide many builds for any
  particular release of your App, you only need to use one new Version
  The number for each new release of your App.
- You cannot re-use Version Numbers.
- For every new build you submit, you will need to invent a new Build
  Number whose value is greater than the last Build Number you used
  (for that same version).
- You can re-use Build Numbers in different release trains, but you
  cannot re-use Build Numbers within the same release train.

You can collect more detail about apple notes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks arjun. so no need worry about the "0.3.0 Before You Submit :Info Needed(iOS)" , can i give video alone & click the button "Submit for Review"?

Comment: Yes exactly! Just upload video and submit

Comment: Thanks arjun. how long it will take for Review

Comment: Give it a day or two.